# How to properly implement setInterval on API Response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am getting api response and appending the response in html table. now i am trying to `setInterval` but the setInterval is not properly set. here is the code.

```js
const settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://datasource.com/price?list",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
};
setInterval(function() {

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {

    var sdata = '';
    $.each(response, function(key, value) {
      sdata += '<tr>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.symbol + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.lastPrice + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.change + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.pChange + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.open + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.dayHigh + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.dayLow + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.previousClose + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.perChange30d + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.perChange365d + '</td>';
      sdata += '<td>' + value.lastUpdateTime + '</td>';
      sdata += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#shares').html(sdata);
    //console.log(response);
  });
}, 5000);
```

```html
<table id="shares">
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>LTP</th>
<th>CHANGE</th>
<th>CHG %</th>
<th>OPEN</th>
<th>HIGH</th>
<th>LOW</th>
<th>CLOSE</th>
<th>30 DAY ROI</th>
<th>1 YR ROI</th>
<th>UPDATED ON</th>
</tr>


</table>
```

How i can implement a working setInterval in the javascript code mentioned above ?

Comment: What do you mean with *"setInterval is not properly set"*?

Comment: the response is not updating automatically. the code is appending the table every time a setInterval triggers.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with `setTimeout("response()", 5000)`. `response` is not a function, as far as I can tell it's an array of objects (you are looping over it in `$.each(response...`). So why are you trying to execute this array of objects like it's a function? I don't get it

Comment: The first thing that happens when your code is executed is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','`. The code crashes immediately, that's probably why your data doesn't get updated. `headers` is an invalid object (`{ "string", "string" }`).

Comment: i am traying to get latest stock data available in response and update that data automatically. with the help of setinterval.

Comment: So instead of appending data each time you want to update the existing values?

Comment: The code you provided here is broken (wrong headers, syntax errors) but your JSFiddle seems to work as intended. Every 5 seconds, data is fetched and appended to `#shares`, exactly as the code says (`$('#shares').append(sdata);`)

Comment: yes @Reyno sir, i want to update the new data with old (existing) data.

Comment: Ah, so maybe don't `append` ? :) Just `.html(sdata)`

Comment: @JeremyThille as we can see @ JSFiddle the data is printing new data every time. i want the new data to be replaced with existing data.

Comment: Yes, I get that, see my previous comment.

Comment: @JeremyThille .html is not updating the data on setInterval.

Comment: Yes, it does. See my answer, I have forked your Fiddle, changed `.append` into `.html` and the whole thing gets updated every 5 seconds. You have updated your original question and fixed the problem directly inside your question. Don't do that, as it voids the question (there is no more problem). I'm reverting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    const settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://datasource.com/price?list",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
};
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

      var sdata = '';
      $('#shares').empty();
      $.each(response, function(key,value){
        sdata += '<tr>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.symbol+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.lastPrice+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.change+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.pChange+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.open+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.dayHigh+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.dayLow+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.previousClose+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.perChange30d+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.perChange365d+'</td>';
        sdata += '<td>'+value.lastUpdateTime+'</td>';
        sdata += '</tr>';
      });
       $('#shares').html(sdata);
 }); }, 5000);
```

```css
    table {
        border: 1px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>LTP</th>
<th>CHANGE</th>
<th>CHG %</th>
<th>OPEN</th>
<th>HIGH</th>
<th>LOW</th>
<th>CLOSE</th>
<th>30 DAY ROI</th>
<th>1 YR ROI</th>
<th>UPDATED ON</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tbody id="shares">
    
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.append(sdata)` appends data (unsurprisingly :) )

If you don't want to append, but replace the whole thing, use `.html(sdata)`.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nx0twgza/)